# Ruby - Create hash with keys and values as arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am new to Ruby and trying to find if I can create a hash which has keys as keys_Array and values as val_array.
Currently I have the following but it gives empty array.

```
key_hash = Hash.new { |hash, key| 
     hash.key = ["#{csv['values']} #{csv['keys']}"]
}
p key_hash.keys #empty array here
```

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're trying to create a hash from two corresponding arrays for keys and values, this is quick way:

```
keys = ["a", "b", "c"]
values = [1, 2, 3]
hash = Hash[keys.zip(values)] 
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>2, "c"=>3}

# for symbols
hash = Hash[keys.map(&:to_sym).zip(values)] 
# => {:a=>1, :b=>2, :c=>3}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make a new hash from two hashes (one contains keys for new hash and other contains values with respect to keys in first hash then only)
you can use something like below :

```
keys = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']
values = ['b1', 'b2']
h = {}

keys.zip(values) { |a,b| h[a.to_sym] = b } 
# => nil

p h 
# => {:k1=>"b1", :k2=>"b2", :k3=>nil}
```

Keep in mind that if the keys are more and values are less in number then key will have nil value as mentioned in the e.g. but if the keys are less as compare to values then it will now consider the remaining values for e.g.

```
keys =['b1', 'b2']
=> ["b1", "b2"]
values = ['k1', 'k2', 'k3']
=> ["k1", "k2", "k3"]
h = {}
=> {}
keys.zip(values) { |a,b| h[a.to_sym] = b } 
=> nil
p h 
{:b1=>"k1", :b2=>"k2"}
```

Comment: Why have you converted the keys to symbols?

Comment: Using symbols not only saves time when doing comparisons, but also saves memory, because they are only stored once.

Comment: The OP hasn't asked for this in their question. If you've made an improvement then give details in your answer. Despite being marked as accepted, currently this answer does not meet the OP's specifications.